# Logging cucumber steps with logger

Tags: automation, cucumber

I am creating cucumber scenarios and I would like to send all output to a file using logger. I would like to output all the gherkin steps during this process. I could just copy the expression from the definition and output it but it would would require added maintenance. Is there a way to access the current step that is executing and line number to output with logger? I have not found any resources on this yet. If there are alternative ways to log information during cucumber test please share!

Comment: Have you looked at the different report formatters? For example, I believe the HTML report formatter already logs all steps and their line number.

Comment: I don't know about other languages, but I know that in the Ruby version it's possible to write your own, custom Cucumber formatters (had to write one because none of the built-in formatters are thread-safe, and I was running tests in parallel). The documentation for that is sparse, but if you're any good at reverse-engineering it's actually pretty straightforward because everything's open-source.